# How to count the number of cells that contain certain text while excluding cells that start the same but end different

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

In our company, the truck numbers in our database all start with "TK" A regular truck would be "TK123" for example. We also have stipend trucks and these all start with "TKPB" meaning their truck numbers would go "TKPB123".

I am trying to count the number of regular trucks (TK) I have every week but I don't want to count the stipend trucks (TKPB). I'm using a pivot table and have created a column that counts the trucks using this formula: `=COUNTIF([@[Unit '#]],"TK*")`.This returns a 1 or a 0. From there, I have my pivot table summing that column. This almost works but it's counting the TKPB trucks as well because they start with TK instead of returning a 0.

How would you tell Excel to count only cells starting with TK followed by a number and not any TKPB cells?

Thank you,
Cole

[image: Picture of my excel sheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `???` instead of `*`,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C3</kbd>

```
=COUNTIFS([@[Unit '#]],"TK???")
```

---

Make sure to change the cell references and ranges accordingly as per your data.

---

Or, may be using the following formula which ensures to take all those starts with `TK` and followed by a number,

[image]

---

```
=COUNTIFS([@[Unit '#]],"TK"&REPT("?",LEN(SUBSTITUTE([@[Unit '#]],"TK",)+0)))
```

---

Or, with :

```
=COUNTIFS([@[Unit '#]],"TK"&REPT("?",LEN(REPLACE([@[Unit '#]],1,2,)+0)))
```

---

Comment: Mayukh, The "???" worked out perfectly. I used the star because that's what I found in another Q&A. Would you mind explaining the difference between the star and the question marks?I'm thinking that the star includes everything while the 3 question marks are placeholders for any letter or number?

Comment: @Cole it represents one single character irrespective of letter or number, that is why I have suggested for the second method, which is dynamic. And it is working since the trucks # are having the pattern of `TK` and 3 numbers but wont work if its `TK8` or `TK83` that is why i have shown the second method which fulfills that problem. and yes `*` Asterix means everything

Comment: Or one more possibility is: `=COUNTIF([@[Unit '#]],"TK*")-COUNTIF([@[Unit '#]],"TKPB*")`